# How to merge two or more arrays value in one array from different files

Tags: php

I have 4 php files all of them is almost same only the table names are different and also the values in the arrays, I want to put all these values in one array in another php file.

this file is Germany.php

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $Home=0;
    $Draw=0;
    $Away=0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Germany where B = '{$val['B']}' AND E = '{$val['E']}' AND F = '{$val['F']}' AND O ='{$val['O']}' AND A = '*' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // output data of each row 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($row['R'] == 1){
                $Home++;
            }elseif($row['R'] == 0){
                $Draw++;
            }else{
                $Away++;
            }
        }

        //We use an array rather than overriding everytime
        $AwayPrediction[$key] = round(($Away/$rowcount )*100);
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

I think I have to do something like that in index.php

```
<table class="table">   
<thead> 
      <tr>
        <th>Home</th>
         <th>Away</th>
         <th>Result</th>
      </tr>
</thead>

    <?php






$array_of_teams=array();
        include 'germany.php';
        foreach($array as $key => $data) {
    $array_of_teams+=merge($AwayPrediction[$key]);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$data['H']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$data['M']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$AwayPrediction[$key]."</td>";
    }

include 'france.php';
foreach($array as $key => $data) {

    $array_of_teams+=merge($AwayPrediction[$key]);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$data['H']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$data['M']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$AwayPrediction[$key]."</td>";
}
```

How can I merge or add $AwayPrediction[$key] to  $array_of_teams=array(); for each file ?

Comment: You should probably just create a stored procedure in your database to do this and handle it in each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP "display" section

```
foreach($array as $key => $data) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$data['H']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['M']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$AwayPrediction[$key]."</td>";
}
```

displays only your last array from `include 'england.php';`
So place a display section after every arrays like

```
include 'germany.php';
foreach($array as $key => $data) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$data['H']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$data['M']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$AwayPrediction[$key]."</td>";
    }

include 'france.php';
foreach($array as $key => $data) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$data['H']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$data['M']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$AwayPrediction[$key]."</td>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it's working now I want to do one last thing, I have now in totally 40 rows on the site what about if I want to sort all 40 rows from highest to lowest(based on .$AwayPrediction[$key]. value)  and display only the first 10 ? Thank you.

Comment: You mean 40 rows from all tables (merged) or 40 from every one ?

Comment: Merged from all tables. I have now two files include on the site you can see on http://goaltips.nl/zeynel/BestMs.php, this is from two different tables. I want to display only 10 highest value(mix from all tables) instead of all rows. I hoop more clear ?

Comment: So collect every table data to one array like $array_of_teams. Sort the array using PHP commnad krsort($array_of_teams) and display it with 40 rows limit (foreach with exit; or for loop with 40 rows condition)

Comment: I am trying to do something like this;  $array_of_teams=array(); and after each foreach($array as $key => $data) { $array_of_teams+=merge($AwayPrediction[$key]); ? Is that correct ?

Comment: Thank you for your help I will create a new question which is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should follow [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and try to minimize code duplication in your codebase. In your case, you can create a function for your duplicated functionality:

```
function predictionForCountry($countryName, $array, $conn)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $Home = 0;
        $Draw = 0;
        $Away = 0;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$countryName} where B = '{$val['B']}' AND E = '{$val['E']}' AND F = '{$val['F']}' AND O ='{$val['O']}' AND A = '*' ";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            // output data of each row 
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if ($row['R'] == 1) {
                    $Home++;
                } elseif ($row['R'] == 0) {
                    $Draw++;
                } else {
                    $Away++;
                }
            }

            //We use an array rather than overriding everytime
            $AwayPrediction[$key] = round(($Away / $rowcount) * 100);
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Another possible solution, if your tables have same number of columns, you can use [UNION ALL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator to merge all your results in SQL, adjust WHERE condition to your needs, if it is different for each country:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Germany where B = '{$val['B']}' AND E = '{$val['E']}' AND F = '{$val['F']}' AND O ='{$val['O']}' AND A = '*' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM France where B = '{$val['B']}' AND E = '{$val['E']}' AND F = '{$val['F']}' AND O ='{$val['O']}' AND A = '*' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM Holland where B = '{$val['B']}' AND E = '{$val['E']}' AND F = '{$val['F']}' AND O ='{$val['O']}' AND A = '*' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM England where B = '{$val['B']}' AND E = '{$val['E']}' AND F = '{$val['F']}' AND O ='{$val['O']}' AND A = '*' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$array` is not changed there and seems to be the same for all countries so are `$key` and `$val` or `$data`.
Each include will override the previous `$AwayPrediction[$key]` and you don't get any differences between countries.

- If you want a global result, you can sum each `$AwayPrediction[$key]` with its previous value, the same with rowcount and before displaying it you calculate the percentage.

in the country files :

```
$rowcount += mysqli_num_rows($result);
$AwayPrediction[$key] += $Away;
```

in index.php

```
echo "<td>".round(($AwayPrediction[$key]/$rowcount )*100)."</td>";
```

- If you want a per country result, you could add 1 dimension to `$AwayPrediction[$key]['Germany']`

Then you can do something like this :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
  foreach ($AwayPrediction[$key] as $country => $prediction) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$data['H']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['M']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$country."</td><td>".$prediction."<td>\n";
  }
}
```